# Saving HTML 5 Canvas via Ajax ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, canvas

I'm trying to sand canvas Data to web service via Ajax, but I get an error:

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

JavaScript:

```
var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
imageData = imageData.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService.asmx/SendRegistration",
    data: "{ 'imageData':'" + imageData + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: AjaxSucceeded
});
```

Web service:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public bool SendRegistration(string imageData)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: could you please confirm two steps first, :

1. you have data in imageData variable
2. Hit post with dummy data to confirm method is receiving your hit.

Answer (score 0):

When the `data` is a string it must be a query string. Don't use string, simply use an object and jQuery will convert it for you:

```
data: { imageData: imageData },
```

If you really want to make the string by yourself, use:

```
data: "imageData=" + imageData",
```

Remember, it's a query string, so the format is `x=1&y=2&z=3`.

Comment: it's not work.. did i need to make a JSON.stringify to the Data

Comment: No, you don't need `JSON.stringify`. Edit your question and add the complete code for `SendRegistration`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, I had to add this code due to a huge file.

```
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
```